# Server truncates/interrupts output when request comes from external computer, but not from 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, apache, wamp, easyphp

Setup:
EasyPHP Dev server 13.1VC11  (Apache 2.2.4, MySQL 5.6.12, PHP 5.5.0)
Windows 7. 
Apache is set up with multiple virtual hosts each pointing to a separate folder under ...data\localweb\.
Server also acts as a gateway between internet and local network.

My wife has made a webpage which includes JavaScript and jQuery and PHP.

When I open a browser on my server computer and access the pages, everything works as they should. Via both these addresses:

```
http://127.0.0.1/liselotte/projekt5/2vs.php
http://liselotte.mine.nu/projekt5/2vs.php
```

However, when I try to access the page from another computer on my local network, the two longer pages in my wife's project gets truncated. (file **2vs.php**, also accessible on the page's main menu as "**V/S**") It always gets truncated at the same place, in the middle of a 8-letter word, in a piece of HTML formatted text.
I use Firefox and can see when the code cuts off before the browser displays an error message that "transfer was aborted". (It's in Swedish, so I'm a bit uncertain about the exact wording of the message) "The connection to the server was severed during retrieval of the page". (no HTTP-error number)

I have also tried Internet Explorer and Chrome, transfer is cut off at the exact same place every time.

Weirdly enough, the page seems to work when accessed from internet.

The Apache config file contains

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen trilliadin.mine.nu:80     #which is one of the virtual hosts
Listen 192.168.137.1:80          #which is Windows local address assigned to my LAN
```

I've tested disabling all firewalls, but no difference.
I dumped about 4MB text into a file.html to see if this also gets truncated but the whole text-file gets transferred.
Does anyone recognize these symptoms?

EDIT:

Regarding error-reporting... I do get some weird apache-errors when I start the server.

```
[Wed Jan 15 21:13:37.989659 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 968:tid 424] AH00424: Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
Failed loading D:\EasyPHP\binaries\php\php_runningversion\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jan 15 21:13:39.861663 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 968:tid 424] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.5.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 15 21:13:39.861663 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 968:tid 424] AH00456: Server built: Apr  8 2013 13:46:39
[Wed Jan 15 21:13:39.861663 2014] [core:notice] [pid 968:tid 424] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\EasyPHP\\binaries\\apache\\bin\\apache.exe -d D:/EasyPHP/binaries/apache'
[Wed Jan 15 21:13:39.861663 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 968:tid 424] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5240
[Wed Jan 15 21:13:40.017663 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5328:tid 436] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
Failed loading D:\EasyPHP\binaries\php\php_runningversion\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jan 15 21:13:41.655666 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5240:tid 432] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

But I don't understand what it means. Tonight, the Virtual Host liselotte.mine.nu became unresponsive, while virtual host trilliadin.mine.nu continued working. The problem resolved when I restarted the apache server. (see error log above)

Comment: A die or exit in the code perhaps? Could be an edge-case related to location or hostname?

Comment: No die or exit in code.
Please elaborate "edge-case related to hostname"...

Comment: It could be very well related that your code relies on your hostname, say ```if (substr($hostname, 0) !== 'myhost') { $do->something(); }```. something() can trigger an error and therefore only fail in specific edge-cases. Another issue could be out of memory or a segfault. Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: The only php code in one of the truncated files is <?php include 'include.php'; ?> <!--footerinclude-->

Comment: I should add, the only thing the included file contains is a html-coded page-footer.

Comment: Regarding error-reporting... I do get some weird apache-errors when I start the server.